# Importing PhraseExpress Snippets to Textexpander

Tags: windows, macos, mac, textexpander, phraseexpress

Is there anyway of importing text snippets made using **PhraseExpress** in windows to **TextExpander** on mac?

I know you can import TextExpander snippets to PhraseExpress but can you do the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

PhraseExpress 9.1 can now sync with TextExpander in both directions: http://www.phraseexpress.com/textexpander-windows.htm

Comment: Would love to have the ability to be able to export phrases to text, csv built into PhraseExpress.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you can't do that. PhraseExpress uses a proprietary export method that only allows those files to be imported into PhraseExpress.

Long answer: There's no easy way. However, if you copy your PhraseExpress snippets to a csv-file (like Excel or OpenOffice Writer), you can reimport that file into TextExpander. You won't be able to preserve any macros. And you will either have to copy and paste all the snippets and their descriptions one by one or write a script that copies all from those files and writes them elsewhere. (I did something like that a while ago with AutoHotkey.)

EDIT:
I've found the AutoHotkey script that I had created to copy from the PhraseExpress window to an Excel spreadsheet. It is for the German version of PhraseExpress, you'll have to adjust the keyboard shortcuts used. (Or I may do that later if I get around to doing it.)

Here's the AutoHotkey code:

```
    ; Edit, Exit, Suspend
+!e::Edit
+!x::ExitApp
+!s::Suspend

; Reload section
#IfWinActive, ahk_class SciTEWindow
F9::
send ^s
Reload 
Return


#IfWinActive ahk_class TpexMWnd4

F5::
Clipboard = 
SendInput !b^a^c ; Beschreibung kopieren
ClipWait
Beschreibung := Clipboard

SendInput {tab} ; Textbausteininhalt kopieren
Clipboard = 
SendInput ^a^c 
ClipWait
Inhalt := Clipboard

; Autotext kopieren
clipboard = 
SendInput !a
SendInput ^a^c 
sleep 100
autotext := Clipboard

; zu excel wechseln und in Zellen eintragen, danach in untere Reihe wechseln
WinActivate ahk_class XLMAIN
WinWaitActive ahk_class XLMAIN
Sleep 200
SendRaw %Beschreibung%
Sleep 100
SendInput {tab}
Sleep 100
SendRaw %inhalt%
Sleep 100
SendInput {tab}
Sleep 100
SendRaw %Autotext%

Sleep 100
SendInput {down}
Sleep 100
SendInput {home}
Sleep 100

; Zu pex wechseln
WinActivate ahk_class TpexMWnd4
Sleep 200
Send !u
Sleep 200
send {down}
Sleep 200
Return


F6::
Clipboard = 
SendInput !b ; zu Beschreibung gehen 
SendInput {tab} ; Textbausteininhalt kopieren
Clipboard = 
SendInput ^a^c 
ClipWait
Inhalt := Clipboard

; Autotext kopieren
clipboard = 
SendInput !a
SendInput ^a^c 
sleep 100
autotext := Clipboard

; zu excel wechseln und in Zellen eintragen, danach in untere Reihe wechseln
WinActivate ahk_class Notepad
WinWaitActive ahk_class Notepad
Sleep 100
SendRaw %Autotext%
Sleep 100
SendInput {tab}
Sleep 100
SendRaw %inhalt%


Sleep 100
SendInput {enter}
Sleep 100


; Zu pex wechseln
WinActivate ahk_class TpexMWnd4
Sleep 200
Send !u
Sleep 200
send {down}
Sleep 200
Return
```

If this is too tedious for you, it might just be easier to recreate the snippets in TextExpander.

Maybe if you contact PhraseExpress Support, they will help you, but otherwise there is no simple way of sharing your PhraseExpress snippets with Textexpander, neither through sync, nor through import.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this myself while looking for a solution to the same problem:

1. I highlighted all snippets and folders,
2. Went to { File > Save As... },
3. On the pulldown for file type, I selected {*.textexpander}.

That's all there is to it. Mind you, I have yet to verify that this works, especially any macro conversions, but I figure if PE can import from TE, they can probably write a file in the same format.

Godspeed.

Comment: When you save as `.textexpander` file format, this format is different from the format that **text expander for mac** uses. The `.textexpander` file format that Phrase Express saves as is a compressed zip file that is renamed to `.textexpander` which is also what the **Phrase Express** proprietary `.pxp` format does and when you open it using a text editor you get unreadable text. This is unlike **text expander for mac** which can easily be opened and edited using a text editor.